# ControlTemplate is not working when embedded into another control

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

Because the existing ComboBox controls don't satisfy my expectations when it comes to flag-enums I created a custom control for it.

Basically I just created a style for a dropdown button and a class inheriting from a dropdown button which provides data sources.

This is my style I created:

```
<Style TargetType="dx:DropDownButton" x:Key="FlagEnumEditStyle">
    <Style.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualContent, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="PopupContent">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White">
                <ScrollViewer Margin="5,5,0,5" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="0,0,5,0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <CheckBox Content="None" Visibility="{Binding HasNoneValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" IsChecked="{Binding NoneChecked}" />
                        <CheckBox Content="All" Visibility="{Binding HasAllValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" IsChecked="{Binding AllChecked}" />
                        <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding IsFlagEnum, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" />
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I create a "FlagEnumEdit" control (that is the class that inherits from `DropDownButton`) and set it's style to that one specified, then it works just great.

Now I got the *DevExpress Grid* which allows me to create custom cell editors by specifying a `ControlTemplate` and binding it's target to the `EditValue` (see their [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/6131/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Editing-and-Validation/Inplace-Editors/Custom-Edit-Template)).

But when I do this, I get errors on all bindings in the style:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=(0).TextDecorations; DataItem='EditGridCellData' (HashCode=14515408); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'TextDecorations' (type 'TextDecorationCollection')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=(0).TextDecorations; DataItem='EditGridCellData' (HashCode=14515408); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'TextDecorations' (type 'TextDecorationCollection')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=(0).TextDecorations; DataItem='EditGridCellData' (HashCode=14515408); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'TextDecorations' (type 'TextDecorationCollection')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=ActualContent; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HasNoneValue; DataItem=null; target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=NoneChecked; DataItem=null; target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HasAllValue; DataItem=null; target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=AllChecked; DataItem=null; target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=IsFlagEnum; DataItem=null; target element is 'Separator' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Items; DataItem=null; target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'HasNoneValue' property not found on 'object' ''FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor')'. BindingExpression:Path=HasNoneValue; DataItem='FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor'); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=HasNoneValue; DataItem='FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor'); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=HasNoneValue; DataItem='FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor'); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HasNoneValue; DataItem='FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor'); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'HasAllValue' property not found on 'object' ''FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor')'. BindingExpression:Path=HasAllValue; DataItem='FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor'); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=HasAllValue; DataItem='FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor'); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=HasAllValue; DataItem='FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor'); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HasAllValue; DataItem='FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor'); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsFlagEnum' property not found on 'object' ''FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsFlagEnum; DataItem='FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor'); target element is 'Separator' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=IsFlagEnum; DataItem='FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor'); target element is 'Separator' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=IsFlagEnum; DataItem='FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor'); target element is 'Separator' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=IsFlagEnum; DataItem='FlagEnumEdit' (Name='PART_Editor'); target element is 'Separator' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
```

This is my edit template:

```
<dxg:GridControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PermissionEditorTemplate">
        <ui:FlagEnumEdit Name="PART_Editor" Style="{StaticResource FlagEnumEditStyle}" Target="{Binding EditValue, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</dxg:GridControl.Resources>
```

I tried to use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` in my style but then the bindings do not work at all anymore. The `ItemsSource` binding does work obviously because when I test it all my checkboxes appear. But when I try to check one, the popup closes and the target property does not change at all.

I'm not sure why this is not working when the control is inlined. And I'm worried why it's working partially.

Here's the class itself ([Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/zPPP99GA)) in case you need it. Haven't cleaned up the class yet, made this when I wasn't really fit so it's quite messy.